# locate a circle more accurately

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, vision

I'm new bee in vision machine.
Currently, I'm detecting circle(hole) from camera.
The green border show circle detected.
Problem is detected circle position deviate +-2pixel.
For example, when I print the circle center position

( 750, 650 ) ->

( 748, 652 ) ->

( 750, 650 ) ->

( 752, 648 ) ->

( 750, 650 )

like this,,

Some one said this could be solved by subpixel algorithm but not sure.

Is it possible to fix the illumination maintaining in vision ?

I just used Opencv-python Library HoughCircle.

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray_frame,
cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,
1,
300,
param1=74,
param2=16,
minRadius=310,
maxRadius=340
)
```

[image]

Comment: how do you calculate the center ? you are working on a live stream ?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk Hi, right I calculate center every 100msec when frame refresh.

Comment: you can not expect to get the same circle contour for each frame, so it would be better to get an avarage by calculating the centert with (lets say) 100 frame. by getting many samples you will get the correct center points. with the help of averaging or standard deviation or ..

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk, Have you ever used subpixel algorithm ?

Comment: needs debugging info, including source data. please review [mre] and [ask]. do that and we can help. -- you *can* expect the circle to not jitter as much, if you used a better algorithm... but we don't know what you did because you aren't showing us! -- machine vision libraries use approaches (lots of 1d sampling) that are different from "computer vision" libraries (academic stuff). you can emulate them however.

Comment: Please post the original image without annotations. We cannot solve a problem that we cannot reproduce.

Comment: this question is unanswerable. there is _still_ no input data.